# Mongodb - "comment" as field name

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing mongodb database which is used in production.

For performance issues - in the projection I select specific fields, and return them to the client.

One of those fields is `comment`, which causes the `collection.find` to return the object with all the fields (since `comment` is a reserved word), which is not what I've expected.

Is there any configuration or a solution that will allow the field to be called `comment` besides renaming the field?